# etcd on GCE-load balancing and health checks

Tags: https, google-compute-engine, healthcheck, etcd

I'm trying to set up a secure etcd cluster on CoreOS on top of GCE.
I want to distribute load between several etcd nodes with some kind of load balancing. I want a load balancer that would have an external IP(to make etcd cluster reachable for other purposes from anywhere) and which would be able to distribute load to the pool of nodes. It seems that GCE Network load balancer meets all these criteria but there is a problem-its only able to use legacy HTTP health check to verify working nodes.
Also, there is an internal regional load balancer, but as its' name says-it gives only internal IP address to a LB, so the cluster would be unavailable from outside.
Are there any known workarounds? Maybe there is some way to host /health for etcd with insecure HTTP. Maybe there is some way to attach HTTPS health check to Network load balancer? Maybe there is some kind of proxy, which is able to check /health and then report it via HTTP? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After contacting etcd team, it looks like I have an answer to my own question =)
[They will add a separate /metrics on insecure port](https://github.com/coreos/etcd/issues/8363)

I think it just a matter of time now. Waiting for next release